# Can oracle Pipelined table function improve performance over normal view

Tags: oracle, plsql, view, sqlperformance, pipelined-function

I have a bit complex oracle view which i use to generate live report. Since all the rows of deriving table is pulled, there is little scope of improvement either by indexing or partitioning.

I wanted to know if I can anyway use pipelined table function to improve the performance of my report.

This came to my mind because I am not sure how exactly the SQL works. Does the queries waits untill all rows from the tables are fetched or it works like a pipelined table function in a way as soon a row is fetched from underlying table it is processed.

Answer (score 3):

A SQL query returns rows as soon as they are available.  Depending on the optimizer query plan this may be "immediately" or there may be a significant delay while records are gathered and sorted, etc.

Using a pipelined function cannot improve this performance, because the pipelined function has to first get some data back from a query and then start piping it out.  It will not get the data from the query any faster than you will.